# How to show graph in Atom using PyPlot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, backend, using

I am using Julia in Atom on a MacBook Pro and I do not succeed in getting a plot Window within or outside Atom when I use PyPlot.

Here is the package status :

....

(v1.1) pkg> status

```
Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.1/Project.toml`

[c52e3926] Atom v0.8.2

[7073ff75] IJulia v1.18.0

[e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.7.0

[d330b81b] PyPlot v2.8.0

[ade2ca70] Dates
```

...

I try the following code :

...

```
using PyPlot

plot(rand(10))
```

...

And I get :

...

```
1-element Array{PyCall.PyObject,1}:

PyObject <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x12963c9e8>
```

....

If I try :

...

```
plt.show()
```

...

I get :

...

/Users/Didier/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/matplotlib/figure.py:445: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  % get_backend())

...

There are plenty discussions about Backends with PyPlot (i.e. Matplotlib inside Julia) but nowhere I found a rationale to modify the backend used by Matplotlib within Atom.

Does somebody have a clear idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PyPlot.display_figs()` as in this example:

```
using PyPlot

plot(1:5,(1:5).^2)

PyPlot.display_figs()
```

When working in the console `PyPlot.show()` could be a good idea.

Finally, you can always just save your picture to a file with the `savefig` command e.g. `savefig(raw"c:\temp\aa.png")`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's the first time I see an efficient and short answer to this question though I spent a while searching for an answer!

Comment: While I am there could you tell me how to save the displayed figure? 
But really thanks for your previous help!

Comment: why if the same is in a julia script instead of displaying figure I get the error: ERROR: TypeError: in cglobal, expected Symbol, got JuliaInterpreter.SSAValue

Comment: When running a script perhaps you want `savefig` just to save it to a file - I edited the answer.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I'm using JuliaPro so there is no way to open plots in the proper tab as it happens with MATLAB?

Comment: Atom Juno has a tab for plots. Unfortunately the GUI for plotting is probably not as nice as in Matlab.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel so the only way to see the plots is to run the code and then type PyPlot.display_figs() there is no way to let figs appear programmatically from the code

Comment: "there is no way to let figs appear programmatically from the code" - this is very imprecise statement - e.g. what you mean by 'appear programmatically'. Which canvas you want to display them on? Perhaps Jupyter solves your question, perhaps other plotting devices or backends?. I think you should make a new question with details what you need and I guess you should get help :-)